# using realloc in c

Tags: c++, c

i am using `void *realloc(void *pointer, size_t size);` to increase the size of my pointer. how does realloc work?
does it create a nre address space, and copy the old value to the new address space and returns a pointer this address? or it just allocates more memory and binds it to the old one?

Comment: You can easily find answer in man pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Realloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684288/understanding-realloc)

Answer (score 5):

[@Iraklis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322364/using-realloc-in-c/5322397#5322397) has the right answer: it does the second (if it can get away with it) or the first (but only if it has to).

However, sometimes it can do neither, and will fail. Be careful: If it can't resize your data, it will return `NULL`, but the memory will ***NOT*** be `free`d. Code like this is wrong:

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, size);
```

If `realloc` returns `NULL`, the old `ptr` will never get `free`d because you've overwritten it with `NULL`. To do this properly you must do:

```
void *tmp = realloc(ptr, size);
if(tmp) ptr = tmp;
else /* handle error, often with: */ free(ptr);
```

On BSD systems, the above is turned into a library function called `reallocf`, which can be implemented as follows:

```
void *reallocf(void *p, size_t s)
{
    void *tmp = realloc(p, s);
    if(tmp) return tmp;
    free(p);
    return NULL;
}
```

Allowing you to safely use:

```
ptr = reallocf(ptr, size);
```

Note that if `realloc` has to allocate new space and copy the old data, it *will* `free` the old data. Only if it can't resize does it leave your data intact, in the event that a resize failure is a recoverable error.

Comment: `ptr = realloc(ptr, size);` is not wrong if followed by `if( !ptr ) fatal_error();` ... and it's rare to do anything else. Of course, if you do try to recover from OOM by freeing existing data (e.g., weak pointers), then the `ptr =` usage is quite bad. The moral is that you should never call plain `malloc` or `realloc`, only wrapped versions that possibly attempt to recover memory and die or throw an exception (longjmp in C) if the memory can't be allocated. Of course, if programming in C++, one should use `new` or, better yet, the STL.

Comment: @Jim - Not necessarily. If you have an array or string library (in plain C) that needs to resize internal, the library should not be expected to die if it can't resize the buffer appropriately, but it also shouldn't be expected to throw away all your existing data.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the proposed implementation of `reallocf`. Particularly, `p` could be `NULL`. if `tmp == NULL`, you'd `free` a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian `free(NULL)` does nothing, it's perfectly safe to do.

Answer (score 3):

It depends! If its unable to resize the memory region in place then it allocates a new memeory region, copy the old data and free the old memory.

Answer (score 2):

You're misusing the term "address space". All of the memory of your process exists within a single address space. The memory not used by your program, its global variables, and its stack are known as the "heap". `malloc` and `realloc` (and `calloc`, which is just `malloc` and clear) allocate memory from the heap. Most implementations of `realloc` will check if there is enough (`size` bytes) free space starting at `pointer` (which must point to a block previously allocated by `malloc` or `realloc` -- `realloc` knows how large that block is) and, if so, just increase the size of the block allocated at the location given by `pointer` and return, with no copying. If there isn't enough space, it will do the equivalent of `newptr = malloc(size); memcpy(newptr, pointer, size_of_old_block); free(pointer); return newptr;` ... that is, it will allocate a block big enough to hold `size` bytes, copy the data at `pointer` to that block, free the old block, and return the address of the new block.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is function is dependent on the requested size and available heap.

From the programmers perspective, I think all we get guaranteed is that `pointer` is non-null if the new allocation is successful.  The pointer may, therefore, remain unchanged even though it now points to a larger block of memory represented by `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Realloc does not change the size of your pointer, the size of pointers is always the same on the same architecture. It changes the size of the allocated memory to which your pointer points. The way it works is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbebcx7d.aspx. In short, yes, it allocates more memory leaving your content unchanged; if the memory must be moved, it copies the content. OF course, you can specify a shorter size, in which case it trims the allocated memory, again leaving the content untouched.