# Concatenation using strcat and realloc produce unexpected errors

Tags: c, linux, string, gcc, string-concatenation

I have encountered so called cryptic `realloc` `invalid next size error` , I am using `gcc` on `linux` my code is

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>

int main()
{
 int i;
 char *buf;
 char loc[120];
 buf = malloc(1);
 int size;

 for(i=0;i<1920;i++)
  {
    sprintf(loc,"{Fill_next_token = my_next_token%d; Fill_next_token_id = my_next_token_id = my_next_token_id%d}",i,i);
    size = strlen(buf)+strlen(loc);
    printf("----%d\n",size);

    if(!realloc(buf,size))
    exit(1);
    strcat(buf,loc);
    }
  }
```

(mine might be duplicate question) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939091/realloc-invalid-next-size) the solution somewhere lies by avoiding `strcat` and to  use `memcpy` , But in my case I really want to concatenate the string . Above code works for good for such 920 iterations but in case 1920 `realloc` gives invalid new size error. Please help to find alternative of concatenating , looking forward to be a helpful question for lazy programmers like me .

Comment: possible duplicate of [using realloc in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322364/using-realloc-in-c)

Comment: Please take care of the title when asking a question here. This is very low quality.

Comment: I came here for help , anyways thank for the advice will keep in mind.

Comment: *looking forward to be a helpful question for lazy programmers like me*  That does **not** make me want to help

Comment: thanks @degustaf , the fix got in answer worked well but it may cause for performance issue while appending to string in 10^n nth iterations . can you still will not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

- **You are not accounting for null terminator when deciding on the new length** - it should be `size = strlen(buf)+strlen(loc)+1;`
- **You are ignoring the result of `realloc`** - you need to check it for zero, and then assign it back to `buf`
- **You do not initialize `buf` to an empty string** - this would make the first call of `strlen` produce undefined behavior (i.e. you need to add `*buf = '\0';`)

Once you fix these mistakes, your code should run correctly:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
   int i;
   char *buf= malloc(1);
   *buf='\0';
   char loc[120];

   for(i=0;i<1920;i++) {
      sprintf(loc,"{Fill_next_token = my_next_token%d; Fill_next_token_id = my_next_token_id = my_next_token_id%d}",i,i);
      int size = strlen(buf)+strlen(loc)+1;
      printf("----%d\n",size);
      char *tmp = realloc(buf,size);
      if(!tmp) exit(1);
      buf = tmp;
      strcat(buf, loc);
   }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/8ZL1y4)

Comment: Thanks , Initially i dint thought those fundamental things because this code was working for some 1200 iterations. I thought there must be something else either than starcat , because appending at 2000th iteration it had to go through around 150KB of characters . Anyways that code worked

Comment: why using a tmp variable and not directly buf?

Comment: @perrocallcenter That's an excellent question! The reason you need to use a temporary is to be able to handle the situation when `realloc` returns `nullptr` more gracefully than simply calling an `exit(1)`. Without a `tmp` you'd be unable to `free` the memory block that you are re-allocating, because its address would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

`buf` is not a valid string so `strcat()` will fail since it expects a `\0` terminated string.

If you want to `realloc()` `buf` then you should assign the return value of `realloc()` to buf which you are not doing.

```
char *temp = realloc(buf,size+1);
if(temp != NULL)
buf = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Point 1. Always use the return value of `realloc()` to access the newly allocated memory.

Point 2. `strcat()` needs a null-terminating string. Check the first iteration case.